# How to get code in Slick Carousel to respond and work properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js

I'm working with this premade Slick Carousel code. ( from here http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ )

What I'm trying to do is add an 'X' to each div so that it could eventually be programmed to remove that element from the carousel. This would replace the "Remove Slide" button, so I commented out the code for that.

The error: The X does not react when it's clicked on. In the fiddle, I've tried to get it to even show an alert when clicked, but that isn't working.

Does anyone know how to get the X button to react when clicked? Furthermore, how could the X button be properly coded?

http://jsfiddle.net/neowot/py3y5346/

HTML

```
<body>

    <section id="features" class="blue">
        <div class="content">       
            <hr id="demos"/>
            <h2>Add & Remove</h2>
            <div class="slider add-remove">
                <!--<div><h3>1</h3></div>-->
            </div>

            <div class="buttons">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button js-add-slide">Add Slide</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="button js-remove-slide">Remove Slide</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>
```

CSS

```
.sliderX{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 20px;
    top:-40px;
    right:-50px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var slideIndex = 0;
    $('.add-remove').slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
    });


    $('.js-add-slide').on('click', function() {
        slideIndex++;
        $('.add-remove').slick('slickAdd','<div><h3><a class="sliderX">X</a>' + slideIndex +
                               '</h3></div>');
    });

    $('.sliderX').on('click', function() {
        alert('Clicked');
    });

    /*Original Code
    $('.js-remove-slide').on('click', function() {
        $('.add-remove').slick('slickRemove',slideIndex - 1);
        if (slideIndex !== 0){
            slideIndex--;
        }
    });
    */

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element $('.sliderX') must be in the DOM in order to bind a click handler. The binding is happening when the JS is originally read in, so the X is not there yet.

You can either move the code that binds the event inside the other click handler that puts the X in the DOM, or delegate the click handling to an event that *is* already in the DOM ie.
```

```
$('body').on('click', '.sliderX', function() {
    alert('Clicked');
});
```

```

This is probably the better plan, b/c it won't create excessive handlers and you don't risk running back into the original problem in should the event that adds the X be asynchronous.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help.